# How can I make an array of integers fit within a range?

Tags: php, arrays, normalization

Just say I want to take an array of numbers:

```
$a['a'] = 10;
$a['b'] = 20;
$a['c'] = 500;
$a['d'] = 1000;
```

And force them to fit within a range (e.g. 1 to 100) like so:

```
$a['a'] = 1;
$a['b'] = 2;
$a['c'] = 50;
$a['d'] = 100;
```

Another example...

From:

```
$a['a'] = 12;
$a['b'] = 28;
```

To:

```
$a['a'] = 1;
$a['b'] = 100;
```

What's the best way to go about it?

Comment: What do you feel is less than optimal about your attempts so far? :-)

Comment: You need 2 passes through the array - once to find the max and min numbers, the 2nd pass to normalize the numbers.

Comment: To be clearer: wanting to maintain the same ratio of distribution between the numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Update:***

Now I understand what you actually want, you need to use this formula:

```
       (new_max - new_min)(x - min)
f(x) = ----------------------------  + new_min
                max - min
```

E.g.:

```
$a = [
    'a' => 10,
    'b' => 20,
    'c' => 500,
    'd' => 1000,
];
$min = min($a);
$max = max($a);
$new_min = 1;
$new_max = 100;
foreach ($a as $i => $v) {
    $a[$i] = ((($new_max - $new_min) * ($v - $min)) / ($max - $min)) + $new_min;
}
var_dump($a);
```

Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/hwGnhJ

---

***Old answer:***

You can use [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php), and [`min`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php)/[`max`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) for that:

```
$a = [1, 2, 1000];
array_walk($a, function(&$value) {
    $value = max(min($value, 100), 1);
});
var_dump($a);
```

Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/jjOCjx

Or just a simple `foreach` and `if`:

```
foreach ($a as $i => $v) {
    if ($v > 100) $a[$i] = 100;
    elseif ($v < 1) $a[$i] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Add `max(lower_bound, $value)` as well, because the OP asked for a range, not just an upper_bound.

Comment: Not quite what was asked for. The numbers should have the same distribution, not simply be capped.

Comment: @deceze That too! But now you see the limitations of the way you asked the question. It's too brief, doesn't describe what you want, what you tried, which makes it easy to misread. :-)

Comment: Result with your algorithm: `[10, 20, 100, 100]`. Desired result: `[1, 2, 50, 100]`.

Comment: Thanks for the formula! What form of mathematic equation is this based on so I can figure out how it works? :-)

Comment: @daveaspinall I don't know the mathematical name for it, other than a function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Well that function helped me out big time so thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do this in following manner.

```
$a['a'] = 10;
$a['b'] = 20;
$a['c'] = 500;
$a['d'] = 1000; 

$range =10; // you can define the range here which you want.


foreach($a as $k=>$v)
{

    $a[$k] = $v/$range;

}

print_r($a);
```